# Trying To Apply Forces To Grass Particle System

Tags: particles, hair

This has been a conundrum for me this week, every tutorial I try to follow on YouTube fails to yield results. I'm trying to make grass blow away from a central point using forces and Dynamic Hair settings, but the most it does is scale each particle smaller to bigger and back again instead of bending and rotating as it appears it should based on the tutorials. This is my first try doing this with particles, I've only ever needed them stationary before. My current settings, they only scale for the first ten or so frames then they just stop moving. I have my max distance on my forces set to cover the whole scene, that doesn't seem to change anything. The Force is made to run throughout the simulation, while the Vortex is set to have strength for only a certain point, hoping it makes the grass strongly react to a powerful wind force from that central point. I know I'm missing something, I just don't know what. Thank you for all your continued assistance.

[image: Frame 3]

[image: Frame 4]

[image: Frame 5]

[image: Forces]

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem, appears to be a bug in Blender where at some point physics no longer wish to work, so I have to delete my particles and remake them, then the forces begin to work again. Very well could be a memory issue with my PC, I run into those a lot.